# Weird lines on google maps

Tags: coordinate-system, google-maps, cartography, maps, satellite

[image: A screen shot of google maps]

While I was travelling with my GPS "ON" and tracking my route I found this strange lines in pink and green dotted lines when I zoomed out the map I found that the lines where coinciding with the airport(RGIA AIRPORT HYDERABAD,INDIA) runway lines which is just around 5km from my location.

So, my question is if, this are the runway approach lines then why would it indicate or show in google maps.

Co-ordinates: 17°14'10.5"N 78°28'23.9"E

Comment: Odd. I don't see this in Google Maps in my [browser](https://goo.gl/maps/ZduoxGsvwDU2) or on my Android phone.

Comment: Yeah now it's not but the day when I was traveling at that location it did..